# Importing a .csv files into sql server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I am trying to import a .csv files into my sql Database that has been created on the SQL server 2014. The problem is that my csv tables have different names from the tables that I have create in my own Database. I cannot change the names on the csv files or the names on my database. They have to stay as they are. Can import the csv files into each table on my database without having an error? please help me out, i'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the import export wizard that is packaged with SQL Server, you can set the data source to a flat file such as CSV. It has a built in mapping option as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using import wizard, but once you pick data source and data destination, go to option "edit Mappings", there you can check which columns goes where, just make sure that columns are the same type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Steps:

1. Select the database
2. Right Click and Select the task and click on export
3. Select the source database and click next and select the CSV database as destination
4. click next and do the mapping of Source and destination columns
5. Click next to Finish

Now data will be imported to the database on appropriate columns

Comment: Thank you for replying back, i am just confused are they going to be imported correctly all of my tables (columns&rows) from csv to sql? I mean it doesn't matter if the csv tables they have different names and my sql tables have also different names is that okay?

Comment: yes , it is does not matter you simple map the CSV column with equivalent SQL table column